# How can I set up shell the same way as in Kali?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, zsh

Used kali for a while, it has an awesome zsh now, can I install it on ubuntu? I installed zsh but it doesn't look like on kali. No color differentiation between directories and files, overall gui looks different. How do I setup it exactly as it is on kali?

Comment: Related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655096/what-zsh-theme-does-kali-use

Comment: Refer to this post: [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1781707/1031490)

Answer (score 1):

In the Kali Linux terminal zsh customizations are made to .zshrc directly. You can inspect the [`~/.zshrc` file](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-defaults/-/blob/kali/master/etc/skel/.zshrc) which is included in Kali Linux by default, and choose whatever customizations you want.

Backup your existing `~/.zshrc` before changing its configuration. Run `zsh -d -f` and then `source /path/to/zshrc` to test the changes in the configurations without replacing the existing .zshrc configuration file.